# PHPMailer imagem não aparece no Outlook

Tags: php, phpmailer, outlook

Boa tarde pessoal,

Fiz um sistema que envia e-mails via PHPMailer de uma tabela de clientes no MySQL. Até ai tudo bem, funciona perfeitamente. O problema ocorre quando recebo esse e-mail no Outlook da MS online (outlook.com). A imagem aparece com um ícone como se o link para a mesma estive quebra ou errado. Isso acontece também no host pago, onde esta alojado meu site, a imagem não aparece. Como poderei contornar esse problema?

Segue código que fiz. Mas atenção que funciona bem no Gmail.

```
try{
    $email = $mysql->where('send', 0)->get('cliente');

    // Configutração Server Google Acount RCH - Itaipu
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    $mail->Username = EMP_EMAIL;
    $mail->Password = EMP_PASS;
    $mail->From = EMP_EMAIL;
    $mail->FromName = EMP_NAME;
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->IsHTML = true;
    $mail->Subject = NEWS_SUBJECT;

    $mail->AddCustomHeader("X-MSMail-Priority: 1");
    $mail->AddCustomHeader("Priority: 1");
    $mail->AddCustomHeader("Return-Receipt-To: EMP_EMAIL");
    $mail->AddCustomHeader("X-Confirm-Reading-To: EMP_EMAIL");
    $mail->AddCustomHeader("Disposition-Notification-To: EMP_EMAIL");
    $mail->ConfirmReadingTo = EMP_EMAIL;

    $message = "<html>";
    $message .= "<body>";
    $message .= "<div>";
    $message .= "<img src='http://acma-development.epizy.com/acma/images/Progressiva_Itaipu.jpg'>";
    $message .= "</div>";
    $message .= "</body>";
    $message .= "</html>";

    $mail->msgHTML($message, __DIR__);

    for ($i=0; $i < $mysql->num_rows(); $i++) { 

        $mail->addAddress($email[$i]['Email'], sentenceCase($email[$i]['Nome']));

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $$email[$i]['Email']) . ")" . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
        } else {
            echo "Message sent to: " . $email[$i]['Nome'] . '(' . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $email[$i]['Email']) . ')<br />';

            try{
                $mysql->where('ID', $email[$i]['ID'])->update('cliente', array('send' => '1'));
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo 'Caught exeception: ', $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        // Limpa todos os E-mail e anexospara o próximo loop
        $mail->clearAddresses();
        $mail->clearAttachments();
    }
    // Creating the email body to be sent
} catch(phpmailerException $e){
    echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Não seriam aspas duplas dentro da img no atributo src? `"<img src=\"http://acma-development.epizy.com/acma/images/Progressiva_Itaipu.jpg\">";`

Comment: Oi Kevin vou tentar mas não sei se é isso. Mas obrigado.

Comment: Oi Kevin, testei o que disse acima e continua na mesma. Só no Outlook não consegue aparecer a imagem. Nos outros webmail tudo funciona bem.

Comment: A pouco adicionei a imagem que envio no corpo do e-mail em anexo, em todo lugar chega bem, só no Outlook que não!!!!

Comment: Ah, é apenas no outlook que não funciona?  Não havia entendido isso

Comment: Essa postagem pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708153/send-email-with-phpmailer-embed-image-in-body

Comment: Oi Kevin, cheguei a tentar usar essa função e não deu certo, até "conversei" com o pessoal via github / phpmailer e com alguma ajuda troquei bastante meu código para ficar mais funcional, é o que está acima. Mas consegui colocar para funcionar, no post abaixo tem a solução. Abraços e obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Depois de pesquisar e "ouvir" o que vcs falaram aqui e muitos testes consegui resolver a minha questão. Segue o código de como resolvi e a explicação.

Então, como podem ver no código acima não estava usando um server online (do meu site) para buscar a imagem um HTTP e devido a segurança do Outlook e outros serviços de webmail, isso não é permitido, então alterei para o meu localhost, de onde os e-mails são mandando e tb com a ajuda o Kevin, troquei as aspas simples para as duplas (de ' para ") na tag img. Cheguei também mandar como anexo, mas não deu certo. Só fazendo essas alterações consegui resolver a questão. Segue código funcionando:

```
try{
    $email = $mysql->where('send', 0)->get('cliente');

    // Configutração Server Google Acount RCH - Itaipu
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    $mail->Username = EMP_EMAIL;
    $mail->Password = EMP_PASS;
    $mail->From = EMP_EMAIL;
    $mail->FromName = EMP_NAME;
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->IsHTML = true;
    $mail->Subject = NEWS_SUBJECT;
    //$mail->addAttachment('images/Progressiva_Itaipu.jpg');

    // Pedido de Confirmação de leitura do E-mail enviado
    // Verificar como enviar para um pag php para alterar DB
    $mail->AddCustomHeader("X-MSMail-Priority: 1");
    $mail->AddCustomHeader("Priority: 1");
    $mail->AddCustomHeader("Return-Receipt-To: " . EMP_EMAIL);
    $mail->AddCustomHeader("X-Confirm-Reading-To: " . EMP_EMAIL);
    $mail->AddCustomHeader("Disposition-Notification-To: " . EMP_EMAIL);
    $mail->ConfirmReadingTo = EMP_EMAIL;

    $message = "<html>";
    $message .= "<body>";
    $message .= "<div>";
    $message .= '<img src="images/Progressiva_Itaipu.jpg" alt="img" />';
    $message .= "</div>";
    $message .= "</body>";
    $message .= "</html>";

    $mail->msgHTML($message, __DIR__);

    for ($i=0; $i < $mysql->num_rows(); $i++) { 

        $mail->addAddress($email[$i]['Email'], sentenceCase($email[$i]['Nome']));

        // Debug
        // $mail->preSend();
        // $bodyMsg = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
        // echo $bodyMsg;

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $$email[$i]['Email']) . ")" . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
        } else {
            echo "Message sent to: " . $email[$i]['Nome'] . '(' . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $email[$i]['Email']) . ')<br />';

            try{
                $mysql->where('ID', $email[$i]['ID'])->update('cliente', array('send' => '1'));
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo 'Caught exeception: ', $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        // Limpa todos os E-mail e anexos para o próximo loop
        $mail->clearAddresses();
        $mail->clearAttachments();
    }
} catch(phpmailerException $e){
    echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Inclusive com esse código, tenho o tracker se o cliente abriu ou não o e-mail em questão. Ainda tenho que ver como pegar essa resposta e mandar para uma pag php para alterar o BD marcando que o cliente Y abriu o e-mail da campanha. Se puderem me ajudar, vou ficar muito agradecido e publico aqui meus códigos como fiz essa função.

Podem ver nesse pedaço do código:

```
// Pedido de Confirmação de leitura do E-mail enviado
// Verificar como enviar para um pag php para alterar DB
$mail->AddCustomHeader("X-MSMail-Priority: 1");
$mail->AddCustomHeader("Priority: 1");
$mail->AddCustomHeader("Return-Receipt-To: " . EMP_EMAIL);
$mail->AddCustomHeader("X-Confirm-Reading-To: " . EMP_EMAIL);
$mail->AddCustomHeader("Disposition-Notification-To: " . EMP_EMAIL);
$mail->ConfirmReadingTo = EMP_EMAIL;
```

Obrigado a todos e em especial ao Kevin